# Are these really sincere questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The following questions were migrated to us from Sci-Fi not too long ago:

- [Are the Teletubbies Cyborgs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/are-the-teletubbies-cyborgs)
- [Are the Teletubbies Prisoners?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/are-teletubbies-prisoners)

I'm honestly having a hard time taking these questions seriously because they are about a children's tv show.

They seem to be mostly speculative questions that probably don't have a real answer.  I for one don't think they belong here and should be closed.  What does everyone else think?

Comment: If you want to outlaw speculation, aim at that - the intended audience shouldn't have much of an impact on whether or not something is on-topic. Is Avatar: the Last Airbender or Gargoyles okay, but Teletubbies not? What about Yo Gabba Gabba! or MLP? Where's the cutoff?

Comment: @ian pugsley I'm not saying that teletubbies are off topic, but rather that the speculation about them being cyborgs or prisoners doesn't seem to be questions that were asked to be taken seriously, but rather for popularity.

Comment: You are partially to blame for that impression - as you have bolded the section about it being a childrens show.  I thought the same as @IanPugsley.

Comment: Now we're condemning popularity?

Comment: @DForck42 by the way i also want the same but single close vote is not enough

Answer (score 2):

I think that they are not great questions, but in theory someone might have an interview with a writer or producer on the show who addresses such things - so getting past the initial impression about the triviality of the question, there is no sound reason why we should not take it at face value.

That said, I had already exercised my right as a user to downvote one of them as I thought it was unlikely to be a great question - unfortunately 11 people disagree with me.

Answer (score 1):

I initially said they'd be ok for migration because I thought it would bring about some interesting speculation as well as trial children's shows on the sites.  Granted, not the best examples to do this with, but I didn't think they were too terrible.

While they do appear to be somewhat *jokey*, I honestly don't think they are terrible questions at all.

I don't think they deserve to be fully closed, but down-voted, I can see.

Just my $0.02